# Proximity sensor not working during call. Any fix?

Tags: lumia, settings, nokia-lumia-920, diagnostics

With two Lumia 920s, one works fine, but the other does not disable the screen during a call. Something wrong with the proximity sensor, i guess.

Now, in Windows Phone 7, the Diagnostic tool allowed testing and adjusting this sensor, but apparently this tool doesn't exist in WP8, and i can't find any other ways to adjust the proximity sensor.

Any ideas or workarounds for this?

Comment: Is there any dust over the proximity sensor? It is located on the right of your camera.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known production issue with the Lumia 920, which allows dust to enter the phone and cover the proximity sensor (and the front facing camera).
The only reliable fix is to send the phone to Nokia for repair (warranty covers that, takes just a few days).

See public news like:

- [Nokia Lumia 920 front facing camera and proximity sensor dust fix on the way?](http://wmpoweruser.com/nokia-lumia-920-front-facing-camera-and-proximity-sensor-dust-fix-on-the-way/)
- [How dust gets inside your Nokia Lumia 920's front facing camera](http://www.wpcentral.com/From-Forums-How-dust-gets-inside-Nokia-Lumia-920-front-camera)